# Ways to validate Http request In Java?

Tags: java, apache, http, http-post

I am trying to validate an HTTP request in my server. The http client can send me different requests that some of them may not match my server so in this case I must send a response to the client that there is something wrong with the request.

Before you continue reading , consider that changing the order of the fields names will not affect the response.So the order of the fields does not matter.

For example:
this is a legal request:

```
POST http://localhost HTTP/1.1
HOST: (here is an IP adress)
Content-Length: 50
Connection: Close
Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l
User_Id = 123456
Item_Id = 5007
Color = 1010
```

(NOTE: the request will be legal if it had only these fields names,
if it contained any other fields names it will be consedered as illegal)

And because it is valid request my server will send 200 OK as a response as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Close
Payment: 2755201
```

But, for example if the request had a false value of the fields or unknown field like follows:
Wrong User_Id value:

```
POST http://localhost HTTP/1.1
HOST: (here is an IP adress)
Content-Length: 50
Connection: Close
Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l
User_Id = -2323
Item_Id = 5007
Color = 1010
```

The response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Close
Error_ID: 602
Error_String: Error in user_Id (illegal user ID)
```

Or unknown field name:

```
POST http://localhost HTTP/1.1
HOST: (here is an IP adress)
Content-Length: 50
Connection: Close
Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l
User_Id = 123456
Item_Id = 5007
Sale = 0.5
Color = 1010
```

The response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Close
Error_ID: 602
Error_String: Sale , unknown field name
```

As a validation way I thought about putting all valid fields names in enum and when I get the request I analyze them based on this enum , but I have more valid fields (not only user_Id ,item_Id and color )so applying this way may take a long time and may be inefficient especially because there is no importance to the order of the fields.

this is my server code:

```
@Test
    public void main() throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
        Socket clnt = null;
        while (true)
        {
            clnt = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("after accept in server");
            BufferedReader request = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clnt.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter response = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clnt.getOutputStream()));

            String req = ".", strReq = "";
            try
            {
                req=request.readLine();
                while (!req.equals(""))
                {
                    System.out.println(req);
                    strReq += (req + "\n");
                    req=request.readLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("xxxx");
            }
            System.out.println(strReq);
            String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
            //here will be the rest of the response
            response.write(httpResponse);
            System.out.println(httpResponse);
            response.flush();
        }
    }
```

I'm new at http , so if there is some validation library or any other more efficient way for validation I will be thankful if you can suggest.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing your own HTTP server and it validates things based on your (static) requirements? The first part is hard to do right, and the second part shouldn't be included in the server itself.

Comment: because I want to send a convenient response that matches the request I got

Comment: @Kayaman second part you mean building the response?

Comment: No, first part is hard (writing a proper HTTP server) the second part (validation) shouldn't be included inside the server. Are you writing this for a school project or something?

Comment: yes it is fro a new project

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks and libraries that make this easy, but if you're supposed to write this yourself, it's going to be pretty ugly. You could parse the request into a request object written by you, instead of treating it as just a set of lines. That would make the code at least a bit easier to handle.

Comment: @Kayaman can you suggest me some of these frameworks and libraries ?

Comment: Sure. Rewrite your code in [Spring](https://spring.io/) and you'll get all the boilerplate handled for you. You'll also get DI, various modules for all your persistence, security and who knows what needs.

Answer (score -1):

Use Spring mvc controller. It makes your life easier. Validation will be taken care automatically. For example

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
  public Response addUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
    return userService.addUser(user);
  }

public class User implements Serializable {

private Long id;
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String userName;
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String password;
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

//all getters and setters here

}
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionController {

 @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public  Response handleBadRequest(Exception ex) {
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return response;
}
}
```

All validations will be taken care by annotation @Valid. Exception can be handled if need in Spring global Exception controller